# Should I specify uses-sdk in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

When I uploaded my app into Google Play it displayed `Targed SDK = 30`, but I can't figure out where is it set in app sources.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` does not contain `uses-sdk` section like this:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="NN"
android:targetSdkVersion="NN" />
```

My build tools version is 33.

`build.gradle` contains the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0"
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
    * The following variables:
    * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
    * - androidCompileSdkVersion
    * - qtAndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
    *                   needed to build any Qt application
    *                   on Android.
    *
    * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
    * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
    * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
    *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion
    ndkVersion androidNdkVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.incremental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Do not compress Qt binary resources file
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'rcc'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        resConfig "en"
        minSdkVersion qtMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion qtTargetSdkVersion
        ndk.abiFilters = qtTargetAbiList.split(",")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //Full debug for uploading production and beta builds.
            ndk.debugSymbolLevel "FULL"
        }

        debug {
            //Small debug info for uploading internal testing builds.
            ndk.debugSymbolLevel "SYMBOL_TABLE"
        }
    }
}
```

`android-MyApp-deployment-settings.json`:

```
{
"description": "This file is generated by cmake to be read by androiddeployqt and should not be modified by hand.",
"qt": {"arm64-v8a": "D:/dev/libs/Qt6.4/android/release/arm64-v8a"},
"sdk": "C:/Users/dmitr/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk",
"sdkBuildToolsRevision": "33.0.0",
"ndk": "C:/Users/dmitr/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393",
"toolchain-prefix": "llvm",
"tool-prefix": "llvm",
"useLLVM": true,
"toolchain-version": "clang",
"ndk-host": "windows-x86_64",
"architectures": { "arm64-v8a":"aarch64-linux-android" },
"android-package-source-directory": "D:/dev/repos/examples/src/MyApp/MyAppQt/platform/android",
"application-binary": "MyAppQt",
"qml-root-path" : [ "D:/dev/repos/examples/src/MyApp/MyAppQt","D:/dev/repos/examples/src/MyApp/MyAppQt" ],
"qml-importscanner-binary" : "D:/dev/libs/Qt6.4/windows/./bin/qmlimportscanner.exe",
"rcc-binary" : "D:/dev/libs/Qt6.4/windows/./bin/rcc.exe",
"extraPrefixDirs" : [  ],
"extraLibraryDirs" : [  ],
"zstdCompression": false,
"stdcpp-path": "C:/Users/dmitr/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/"
}
```

Where can this `Targed SDK = 30` come from?

What is the difference between `Targed SDK` and `sdkBuildToolsRevision`?

What is my `Target SDK` if I target Android 13?

**EDIT1:**

For example, `Qt6.4\android\release\arm64-v8a\src\android\templates\build.gradle` contains this:

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfig "en"
    minSdkVersion qtMinSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion qtTargetSdkVersion
    ndk.abiFilters = qtTargetAbiList.split(",")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

targetSdkVersion uses to be located at **build.gradle(:app)** (not project), under android -> defaultConfig

Comment: I do not have it here.

Comment: Are you sure? you can find it by typing Control+Shift+F and look for targetSdkVersion

Comment: It was a good idea, found something like `targetSdkVersion qtTargetSdkVersion` in some `templates` folder. Where `qtTargetSdkVersion` is a variable that is set somewhere in QT. See EDIT1